# Extra cookies appearing in responses

Tags: session, cookies, flask, session-cookies

I'm building my application in Flask, and I'm experiencing some awfully strange behavior with cookies.

My application is served by multiple nodes and as a result I have had to build my own session manager to integrate with Dynamo Db.

It's really simple: 

When a user logs in, if they successfully authenticate, I create a UUID4 to act as their session ID, store this ID along with some data in Dynamo, and then I send a cookie to the user with a `session_id` field set to the generated UUID.

```
if authenticate(user): #validates user credentials
    permissions = get_permissions(user) #gets user permissions
    if permissions:
        #creates session in dynamo
        s = create_session(user['id'], permissions) 
        if s:
            response = make_response(redirect(url_for('index')))
            response.set_cookie('session_id', s['SessionId'])
            return response
        else:
            return 'Internal Error', 500
    else:
        return 'Internal Error', 500
else:
    return redirect(url_for('login', q='invalid'))
```

And for completeness, here is the code for the `create_session` function that actually creates the session:

```
def create_session(user_id, permissions):
    id = str(uuid.uuid4())
    data = {
        'SessionId': id,
        'data': {
            'user_id': user_id,
            'datetime': str(datetime.utcnow()),
            'permissions': permissions
        }
    }
    try:
        s = sessions.put_item(data=data)
    except:
        pass

    return data if s else False
```

However, here is the behavior I am experiencing:
- I login as user 1 in one browser, I successfully authenticate and I am brought to the welcome page, where I can see I am logged in as user 1
- I then login as user 2 in another browser, successfully authenticate and I am brought to the welcome page BUT I can see that I am logged in as user 1
- I then look at the network activity explorers of the browsers and I can see that in the case of user 2, the server replied with 2 SET-COOKIE headers. The first is the cookie user 2 should have been getting but the second is the cookie that only user 1 should be sent. 
The response headers taken from the browser of user 2 looks like:

```
Content-Length:209
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Sun, 13 Sep 2015 13:16:44 GMT
Location:http://dev.remedize.com:8080/
Server:Werkzeug/0.10.4 Python/2.7.9
Set-Cookie:session_id=e67e56cd-cd75-4671-8003-445152a9b850; Path=/
Set-Cookie:session_id=e06a9131-7a2d-4bd0-a7dc-6cd1964633dd; Path=/
```

e67e56cd-cd75-4671-8003-445152a9b850 is the session_id user 2 should be receiving but it is clearly being overwritten by the second header - and I have no idea where that second SET-COOKIE header is coming from. BECAUSE... if I do:

```
@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    print response.headers
```

The very same request shows up in my console with these headers:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 209
Location: /
Set-Cookie: session_id=e67e56cd-cd75-4671-8003-445152a9b850; Path=/
```

That second SET-COOKIE doesn't seem to be appearing on the output.

Note that this doesn't happen every time.

I then considered that this was an issue with my web server, but then I realized it happens on both my dev flask server and my production nginx servers.

As this made absolutely no sense to me, I did a lot of debugging in the code below and I can say for absolute certainty that every time, `create_session` definitely returns a new session, a new UUID. As you can see there is no code to pull any other sessions from Dynamo here.

As a matter of interest, I tried replacing:

```
response = make_response(redirect(url_for('index')))
```

with

```
response = make_response(render_template('welcome.html', user=user, permissions=permissions))
```

and I could no longer recreate the behavior myself, but my users have still noticed random occurrences of this. Looking at my logs, I can see that correct and unique session_ids were generated when they logged in.

If anyone has any ideas where I'm going wrong, I would be eternally grateful. Am I using the cookies in the wrong way? Am I being dumb? Any suggestions would be great. Thanks!!!

Comment: Not directly related, but you should probably use [flask's `session_interface`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.session_interface) so your application code can simply use the `flask.session` dict.